# PHP RegularExpression to replace word at beginning of string, or followed by whitespace

Tags: php, regex

I am a little rusty on Regular Expressions, and so would appreciate assistance. For a current project, I need to sanitize some user input and conver abbreviated UK county names to their verbose counterpart (for example Lincs => Lincolnshire).

I have written a function to handle this which uses Regular Expressions, since we only want to make the replacement when the abbreviation is either at the beginning of the string, or is preceeded by a comma or white space, **and** followed by whitespace (or string termination).

So considering the example of `Lincs`, the following replacements should happen:

`Boston, Lincs` => `Boston, Lincolnshire` (because `Lincs` is preceeded by whitespace)
`Lincs` => `Lincolnshire` (because `Lincs` is at the start of the string)
`Test, Lincsto` => `Test, Lincsto` because `Lincs` has other characters following)

Here's what the function looks like right now:

```
function fullCounties()
{
    $replacements = array(
        'lincs' => 'Lincolnshire'
    );

    $new = $_REQUEST['place'];
    foreach($replacements as $find => $replace)
    {
        $new = preg_replace('/(^|\W)'.$find.'([\W\d])/', $replace, $new);
    }
    echo $new;
}
```

But this simply returns  `Boston, Lincs`, rather than the expected `Boston, Lincolnshire`. Can anyone explain the correct RegExp to match the requirements outlined above, or suggest why this one doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're searching for `Lincs` by using `lincs`, and without the case-insensetive flag this will fail. Also, you may want to look into Word Boundaries (`\b`).

```
$new = preg_replace("(\b".preg_quote($find)."\b)i",$replace,$new);
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be the cleanest solution, and works well.

Comment: @BenM: It might work for you but `\b` (word boundary) don't match with the requirements you stated in you question.

Comment: @anubhava Please explain.

Comment: Well for ex: OP wrote `match should be followed by whitespace` whereas `\b` will match any word boundary not just whitespace like hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

> we only want to make the replacement when the abbreviation is either at the beginning of the string, or is preceded by a comma or white space, and followed by whitespace (or string termination).

Use this code with lookaround regex:

```
$new = preg_replace('/(?<=^|[,\s])'. preg_quote($find) . '(?=\s|$)/', $replace, $new);
```